# Bindings in MVVM not work for Android with ViewModelProviders

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin

After binding, none of the bindings work, for `name` and `onClick`. The button has no text and nothing happens after clicking.

Is it because that `lateinit`? I did it because otherwise I have to make it nullable in order to make Kotlin happy. Because I have to initialize the property when I declare it. Anything I am missing here?

**This is the xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="authViewModel"
            type="nz.salect.handset.viewmodels.AuthViewModel" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        ...
        tools:context="nz.salect.handset.view.AuthActivity">

        ......

            <Button
                ...
                android:onClick="@{ () -> authViewModel.lookAroundHandler() }"
                android:text="@{authViewModel.name}"
                ... />
```

**This is the according view:**

```
class AuthActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var authViewModel:AuthViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth)
        authViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AuthViewModel::class.java)
    }
}
```

**This is the view model**

```
class AuthViewModel:ViewModel() {
    val name = "albert"

    fun lookAroundHandler() {
        println("I am here in view model")
    }
}
```

**dataBinding has been added to `build.gradle`:**

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing binding code

```
val mViewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_auth);
```

you dont need to add this line

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth)`

[https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html](http://Check%20this)

Comment: Thanks. Seems close. So I modified that line to         `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_auth) as ActivityAuthBinding`. Still nothing happens. I just added `    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.1"` to gradle, is it enough for enable data binding?

Comment: Just add  
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    } in gradle file

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_person)
(application as PeopleApplication).applicationComponent.inject(this)

val viewModelFactory: PersonViewModel.Factory = PersonViewModel.Factory(
personDataManager, this)
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(PersonViewModel::class.java)

binding.friendsList.adapter = PersonFriendListAdapter(viewModel)
viewModel.personData.observe(this, Observer<Person> { person ->
    binding.person = person
    person?.friends?.let {
        (binding.friendsList.adapter as PersonFriendListAdapter).setItems(person.friends)
    }
})
 }
```

check your code once